# calling a javascript function in an asp

Tags: javascript, function, asp-classic, call

I am trying to make a photo gallery, when clicking one thumb photo, it has to be shown in the showcase. but somehow the function chng1 cant be called,

```
<script language="javascript">
function chng1(image1,image2)
{
    alert "im here";
    document.getElementById(image1).src = document.getElementById(image2).src;

}
===============================================
   <div class = "photogrid">

   <table>
   <%
    dim i, j, src1,id
    i = 1
    j = 2
    do while i < 14
        src1 = "jor"
        id = "jor"
        src1 = src1 & i & ".jpg"
        id = id & i
    %>
        <tr style = "height:140px;width:250px;"> 
            <td style = "width:100px;">
                <image id = <%=id%>  onClick = "chng1('showcase', '<%=id%>')" src = <%=src1%> style = "position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px;">
            </td>
            <td style = "width:100px;">
                <image src = <%=src1%> style = "position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px;"></image> 
            </td>
            <td style = "width:100px;">
                <image src = <%=src1%> style = "position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px;"></image> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    <%
    i = i + 1
    loop
   %>
   </table>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js function should look like, you can't omit parentheses in JavaScript function call

```
function chng1(image1,image2)
{
    alert ("im here");
    document.getElementById(image1).src = document.getElementById(image2).src;

}
```

`<image>` is not valid html tag, it is `<img>`

```
<img id = <%=id%>  onClick = "chng1('showcase', '<%=id%>')" src = <%=src1%> style = "position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px;">
```